# Move Static Block created from admin panel to above the Breadcrumb in magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, frontend, static-block, admin-panel

If the question was not understandable. I want to move the a block (which contains 2 images) , which was called in a catalog page. The block and catalog page were created in admin panel. i think a move command in "Layout Update XML" field in catalog page should do the job. But i dont know what to give in it.
This was the code that i gave

```
<move element="category.cms" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs">
```

But that didn't work

Basically change from this[image: from] to this [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<move element="category.cms" destination="page.top" after="navigation.sections"/>
```

If you need above Navigation then use :

```
<move element="category.cms" destination="page.top" before="-"/>
```